# Выдаёт ошибку string indices must be integers, что делать?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, vkontakte-api

Что тут не так?

```
if event.text == 'хс':
    users = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(peer_id=event.peer_id, fields='online')
    for user in users:
        print(user['items'][0]['member_id']
```

выдаёт ошибку `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: Что не так, написано в сообщении об ошибке. Разберитесь, что находится в users и соответственно в user.

Answer (score 1):

[getConversationMembers()](https://vk.com/dev/messages.getConversationMembers) возвращает примерно такой словарь

```
{
    'count': 1,
    'items': [
        {
             'member_id': 42,
             'invited_by': 1,
             'join_date': 123456789,
             'is_admin': False,
             'can_kick': False,
        },
        {
             'member_id': 24,
             'invited_by': 1,
             'join_date': 123456789,
             'is_admin': False,
             'can_kick': False,
        },
        ...
    ],
    'profiles': [...],
    'groups': [...],
}
```

Соответственно, у цикла `for user in users:` будет 4 итерации - по одной на каждый ключ словаря. На первой же итерации значением переменной цикла `user` будет строка `count`. А строку нельзя индексировать по ключу `items`.

Правильно написать так:

```
for user in users['items']:
    print(user['member_id'])
```